# Custom database table and custom search

Tags: search, csv

On an existing site I am migrating from there is a csv file (about 5000 rows) and a Perl script that presents the user with a simple search form to display a selection of the fields on a search results page.

I know I could use a custom post type and maybe a plugin like the Participants Database, but I am reluctant to populate WP with this custom data if there is a simpler way of doing it. Here is my approach.

1. Import the data into a new custom Mysql table. - How do I do that? Plugin?
2. Provide a search on the new table. There was
   a plugin that seemed to do that [easy query](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-query/), but it looks
   abandoned.

Am I heading in the right direction or there a better ways of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Import the data: you should be able to do that in your database tool e.g. MySQL Workbench, You don't need to do this through WordPress.

Comment: Easy Query Pro is still getting releases, so I'd hope the free one still works OK even if it hasn't had an update. You can always try it and ask for support. At first glance though I can't see if it's designed for custom tables or just the regular WordPress ones.